# Display Alert Messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visualforce

```
var msg = '<!-- Get Used Parts Code for Mobile Website Redirection -->' + "\n";
msg += '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/global?accountId={!Account.Id}"></script>' + "\n";
msg += '<!-- End of Get Used Parts Code for Mobile Website Redirection -->';
alert(msg);
```

This messages display in alert box.
How to display messages in Visualforce pages.

Current get the error message in

```
Error: The element type "apex:page" must be terminated by the matching end-tag `"</apex:page>"`.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:pageMessages />
```

Apex Controller:

```
ApexPages.Message alertMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error Message.');
ApexPages.addMessage(alertMsg);
```

Comment: I have modified Messages. Can you please looking to this.